# Laravel Queues, disabling for artisan command

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-queue

I have a website set up for customer management.  Each user has a set of customers in various stages.  I have queues set up to watch for a new customer to be created.  So that the stage that customer is in will be checked, and the tally for that stage will be changed.

The problem I am having, is that I am attempting to import several thousand customers.  I would like to have a way to check to see if the customer is being created with an artisan command, to not fire the job.

Alternatively, if there was a way to tell Laravel to stop listening at the beginning of the import script, then start it back up at the end, telling it to re-tally everything.

Are either of these possible? I'm not very familiar with queues.